# Radzen Chart adjustment

Tags: blazor-server-side, radzen

I'm trying to graphically show balance/value of some bank account throughout time. For example, in the period of 2 years there were input/output transactions to/from bank account and they were not done periodically, let's say each day, there were few transactions in same day, then for few months nothing, then again few in the same day etc, so the graph looks messy.

[image: Graph example]

And each of this dot on graph actually represents few transactions in that day and it's not really readable and looks silly, especially this long period of no changes. Is there any way to fix this up a little bit using Radzen or maybe some other tool?

Radzen code I used for shown graph:

```
        <RadzenChart>
            <RadzenLineSeries Smooth="false" Data="@HistoricalTransactionArray" CategoryProperty="Date" Title="Value" LineType="LineType.Solid" ValueProperty="Quote">
                <RadzenMarkers MarkerType="MarkerType.Square" />
            </RadzenLineSeries>
            <RadzenCategoryAxis Padding="1" FormatString="{0:dd-MM-yyyy}" />
            <RadzenValueAxis>
                <RadzenGridLines Visible="true" />
                <RadzenAxisTitle Text="Value" />
            </RadzenValueAxis>
        </RadzenChart>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. I fixed this using Min property of RadzenValueAxis:

```
<RadzenValueAxis Min="null" />
```